# Padding keeps pushing relative elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div with text-align:center and 3 spans with text in them. I also have mouse over event that sets padding,background color and border. But when doing it it pushes the other 2 spans. Here is a jsfiddle for better visualization.

http://jsfiddle.net/93EBu/

```
<div id="div">
   <span class="span">Word</span>
   <span class="span">Word</span>
   <span class="span">Word</span>
</div>



   #div {
       text-align:center;
   }

   .span {
       margin: 0px 5%;
   }

   .spanhover {
       border:1px solid blue;
       background-color:lightblue;
       padding:5px;
   }
```

Comment: I assume that your question is why does it happen and how can i prevent the pushing? Is this the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TRY THIS:

```
#div {
    text-align:center;
}
.span {
    margin: 0px 5%;
    padding:6px;
}
.spanhover {
    border:1px solid blue;
    background-color:lightblue;
    padding:5px;
}
```

DEMO HERE: http://jsfiddle.net/93EBu/1/

The reason you are having this problem is because the padding you are adding to the spanhover class is pushing the elements. So you need to have the span already have the padding as well.... but since you have added a 1px border. You need to make the span padding be 6px... Padding + Border.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove `padding: 5px` from `.spanhover` as well as adding `border: 1px solid transparent` to your `span` elements:

```
#div {
    text-align:center;
}
.span {
    margin: 0px 5%;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}
.spanhover {
    border:1px solid blue;
    background-color:lightblue;
}
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/93EBu/2/)**

Also, instead of using unnecessary jQuery here, you can make use of `:hover` selector:

```
span:hover {
    border:1px solid blue;
    background-color:lightblue;
}
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/93EBu/4/)**